# Trying to send compressed json from python to javascript via websocket

Tags: javascript, python, json, websocket, zlib

I have a websocketserver that I use to communicate from my python to my javascript in the browser. Some of the json I need to send it too big so I used Zlib to compress it in python, like this:

```
zlib.compress(json.dumps(self.data))
```

Now that it is compressed when I send it to my Javascript I have tried to decompress it with Zlib.js and Pako but nothing I try works.

When I do:

```
 function getBlob (blob, cb) {

    var data = pako.inflate(blob);
    var output = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(data));
    cb(output);

  }
```

I get:

```
pako.js:747 Uncaught unknown compression method
```

Any help would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: What are the first ten bytes of what you are feeding to inflate?

Comment: These are the first ten bytes: ᯡࠣ䅌ހ猥ᠩ悇ࠥ恖吡㡠孙

Comment: In hexadecimal please.

Comment: I could convert it to hex using encode but that's not how it is being sent. Do you want me to encode it as hex anyway?

Comment: Yes. There is no other way for you to convey here without loss what bytes are being sent other than encoding it into a readable form somehow. (Hex, base64, decimal, whatever.)

Comment: Sorry didn't think about that. I actually convert it to base64 for the transmission as well. Here are the first ten characters. eJy9l9Fu2z

Comment: That is a zlib stream. Did you get that from what you sent, or from what you received. You need to check that "blob" is that. And are you decoding the base64 before feeding it to inflate?

Comment: Yup, I convert to base64 then I use atob in javascript to convert back and then run pako inflate on that. I have tried running zip in it too. I even copied the base64 string into my javscript and registered it as a variable, atob it, feed it to pako, and I get the same error.

Comment: Have you checked the result of atob to verify that it is exactly what you fed to the base64 encoder at the other end?